# js после нажатие на button получаем значение в div

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, как написать скрипт, который возвращает значение из кнопки
На пример

```html
<button id="button">ABC</button>
<div id="result-btn">ABC</div>
```

То есть после нажатие на кнопку button id=button в div получаем результат значения button

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<button id="button" onclick="document.getElementById('result-btn').textContent=this.textContent">ABC</button>
<div id="result-btn">DEF</div>
```